# Creating a mapped column type for an Abstract class Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm trying to create a `MappedCOlumnType` for an abstract case class that I have.

```
sealed abstract class Address(address: String)
implicit val addressToString = MappedColumnType.base[Address, String](
  addr => addr.address,
  addr => AddressUtil.address(addr)
)
```

but I am getting a compiler error stating that:

```
value address is not a member of com.suredbits.core.protocol.Address
[error]  Note: implicit value addressToString is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[error]   {addr => addr.address } , { addr => AddressUtil.address(addr) }
```

when I am clearly declaring `address` as a field inside of the case class. I feel like this might be an extremely silly error on my part. Why isn't my address field visible?

Answer (score 0):

The `address` in your example is private to the constructor. To make it public with a getter, add `val` to the front of it like so:

```
sealed abstract class Address(val address: String)
```

HTH.